# Update constraint of existing index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I have created a composite index with unique constraint into janusgraph.
After that I have loaded millions of records, but due to some technical problems I have to remove the unique constraint of the index.
Is it possible ?

```
byCodeIndex = mgmt.buildIndex(PropertyConfig.INDEX_CODE_VERTEX_CODE, Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKeyCode).unique().buildCompositeIndex();
```

I dont want to create new index, just want to update the index by removing its unique constraints.